# Find all occurrence of value from column b in column a

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

So basically I have 2 tables which I merge by

```
SELECT t2.columnA , t1.columnB, t1.description
FROM Table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 as t2 on t1.GIDNumber=t2.TwrNumber
```

I need to display all occurrence of value from t1.columnB in t2.columnA

The perfect situation for this dataset is when there is no duplicated value in column A and value of column B matches value from column A, but i know there is a lot of errors.

[image: This image represent dataset]

This is example of situation i want to display. The value of ColumnB which is in red box appears in ColumnA multiple times.

**UPDATE:** Sample data for first query

t2.columnA

```
5900920132278
5900920132278
5900920132278
5900920132278
5900920132278
5900920132278
038548088099
038548088099
038548088099
038548088099
038548088099
5900442707411
5909426907526
5900855046879
4014855166091
5909426909667
```

t1.columnB

```
5900920061554
5900920132278
2010000001165
5900920061479
5900920132261
5900920132278
038548088099
5706915071948
38548088099
038548088099
38548088099
2100000038879
2100000035502
2100000030163
4014855026562
2100000031627
```

In this dataset need to display all records from t2.columnA contains 5900920132278 and 038548088099

**UPDATE 2.** Data from separate queries:

COLUMN A:

```
5900920132278
5900920132278
038548088099
038548088099
038548088099
```

GIDNumber:

```
21801
37273
97191
163053
165153
```

ColumnB:

```
5900920132278
5900920132278
5900920132278
038548088099
038548088099
038548088099
038548088099
```

TwrNumber:

```
21801
37273
91424
21801
37273
91424
```

**Solution :**

```
SELECT t2.columnA , t1.columnB, t1.description
FROM Table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 as t2 on t1.GIDNumber=t2.TwrNumber
WHERE EXISTS 
( SELECT 1 FROM Table2 as t3 WHERE t1.colmnB = t3.columnA ) 
AND t2.columnA <> t1.columnB
```

Comment: There are duplicates in table t2 as you can see. @ypercubeᵀᴹ

Comment: No, I can't see. Please add data from separate queries: `SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE columnB = 5900920132278;` and `SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE columnA = 5900920132278;` A few rows are enough but be sure to include all related columns (columnA, columnB, GIDNumber, TwrNumber)

Comment: ... and desured output on THAT source data.

Comment: GIDNumber and twrNumber are primary keys, Connection condition are imposed by database's documentation. @ypercubeᵀᴹ

Answer (score 1):

**Test Data:**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1( columnA nvarchar(255), columnB nvarchar(255),GIDNumber int, Description nvarchar(255));
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table2( columnA nvarchar(255), columnB nvarchar(255),TwrNum int,Description nvarchar(255));

INSERT INTO dbo.Table1(columnA,ColumnB,GIDNumber,Description)
VALUES(5900920132278,5900021321,1,'F-A1120010185')

,(5900920132278,5900021322,1,'F-A1120010165')
,(5900920132278,5900021323,1,'F-A1120010165')
,(5900920132278,5900021324,1,'F-A1120010165');


INSERT INTO dbo.Table2(columnA,ColumnB,TwrNum,Description)
VALUES(2000061232,5900920132278,1,'F-A1120010185');
```

**Original query**

```
SELECT t2.columnA , t1.columnB, t1.description
FROM Table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 as t2 on t1.GIDNumber=t2.TwrNum;
```

**Result:**

```
columnA columnB description
2000061232  5900021321  F-A1120010185
2000061232  5900021322  F-A1120010165
2000061232  5900021323  F-A1120010165
2000061232  5900021324  F-A1120010165
```

**Adding COUNT() and GROUP BY**

```
SELECT t2.columnB,t2.columnA , count(t1.columnB) as amount_of_matches
FROM Table2 as t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 as t1 on t1.columnA =t2.ColumnB 
GROUP BY t2.columnB,t2.columnA;
```

**Result:**

```
columnB columnA amount_of_matches
5900920132278   2000061232  4
```

---

**If you also need to check if GIDNumber = TwrNum**

```
SELECT t2.columnB,t2.columnA , count(t1.columnB) as amount_of_matches
FROM Table2 as t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 as t1 on t1.columnA =t2.ColumnB and t1.GIDNumber=t2.TwrNum 
GROUP BY t2.columnB,t2.columnA;
```

As a result, if column `B` matches column `A` but the `t1.GIDNumber=t2.TwrNum`  does not match, it will show as no match:

```
columnB columnA amount_of_matches
5900920132278   2000061232  4
```

---

**Extra tests:**

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table2(columnA,ColumnB,TwrNum,Description)
VALUES(2000061232,5900920132279,2,'F-A1120010185');


SELECT t2.columnB,t2.columnA , count(t1.columnB) as amount_of_matches
FROM Table2 as t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 as t1 on t1.columnA =t2.ColumnB 
GROUP BY t2.columnB,t2.columnA;

columnB columnA amount_of_matches
5900920132278   2000061232  4
5900920132279   2000061232  0

INSERT INTO dbo.Table1(columnA,ColumnB,GIDNumber,Description)
VALUES(5900920132278,5900021321,1,'F-A1120010185');

SELECT t2.columnB,t2.columnA , count(t1.columnB) as amount_of_matches
FROM Table2 as t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 as t1 on t1.columnA =t2.ColumnB 
GROUP BY t2.columnB,t2.columnA;

columnB columnA amount_of_matches
5900920132278   2000061232  4
5900920132279   2000061232  1
```

---

**Adding the description column:**

```
SELECT t2.columnB,t2.columnA , count(t1.columnB) as amount_of_matches, t2.Description
FROM Table2 as t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 as t1 on t1.columnA =t2.ColumnB   and t1.GIDNumber=t2.TwrNum 
GROUP BY t2.columnB,t2.columnA, t2.Description;
```

**Result:**

```
columnB columnA amount_of_matches   Description
5900920132278   2000061232  4   F-A1120010185
5900920132279   2000061232  0   F-A1120010185
```